# Prerequisites for Andrew Ng's Machine Learning Course

Tags: machine-learning

I am planning to enroll for Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning. I've no background in math. Is it OK if I start the course and learn math as and when required?

Comment: I think you should ask this question here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43371/the-singularity and delete it from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This course is focused on machine learning using MATLAB, which is not practical nowadays as it is a programming language used specifically for computing, and cannot display GUI or communicate through the network. The language is powerful but limited in some ways. Nowadays most people use python for machine learning, as it is versatile and can connect to other backend like C++, java, JavaScript easily. The language is also a general language, and unlike MATLAB can do many things not limited to computing.

If you really want to join this course, I would recommend first learning MATLAB language and also learn basic calculus like derivatives. This would greatly help on your learning of the course.

However if you want to here serious about machine learning, I would encourage you to enroll in the Deep Learning specialization also by Andrew Ng on Coursera.
https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning
This course uses python as the programming language and teaches more modern approaches to deep learning like recurrent neural networks, convolutional neural networks and more. It also talks more about application of neural network. There is also theory, but it also talks about application of a specific algorithm and how it works.

Hope I can help you.

Comment: Now I have enrolled and the course is starting from 9th Dec 2019.  As I've liking for the course but no background in calculus and linear algebra, I was just thinking how can I learn the concepts as quickly as possible.

Comment: Did you started the deep learning specialization or the Machine learning course that uses MATLAB? I first started deep learning without any calculus experience, but I believe you could learn the basic calculus required for deep learning from Khan Academy easily. Those are not that hard but I strongly encourage you to check it out. Good luck on your course!

Comment: I've started Andrew Ng's Machine Learning.

Comment: Great! Try learning some basic MATLAB and also calculus to get you started. Also as a quick reminder you can finish and complete the course whenever you want, and late submission to homeworks won't affect your mark whatsoever. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No pre-requisites required for Andrew Ng ML course. There are a couple of lectures in which he gives basic idea of Linear algebra. Also you can learn math when required.

Answer (score 0):

I must simply direct you to this excellent blog post on Machine Learning Mastery:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/what-is-holding-you-back-from-your-machine-learning-goals/